# SOAP web service's WSDL different from actual results

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I have to write some php code to get data from a SOAP web service. The WSDL file is different from the actual ws implementation.
This is a wsdl snippet

```
    <s:element name="GetArticoliResponse">
      <s:complexType>
        <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="GetArticoliResult">
            <s:complexType>
              <s:sequence>
                <s:any minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" processContents="lax"/>
                <s:any minOccurs="1" namespace="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1" processContents="lax"/>
              </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
          </s:element>
        </s:sequence>
      </s:complexType>
    </s:element>
```

I'm new to SOAP and wsdl, but my understanding is that the wsdl specification is basically a "catch all" that dumps everything into a stringy blog. As a matter of fact calling `GetArticolo` returns this:

```
 <soap:Body>
        <GetArticoliResponse xmlns="http://redacted.org/">
            <GetArticoliResult>
                <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
                    <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:MainDataTable="Table" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
                        <xs:complexType>
                            <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                <xs:element name="Table">
                                    <xs:complexType>
                                        <xs:sequence>
                                            <xs:element name="ID" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            <xs:element name="GRIFFE" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                                            [...]
                                        </xs:sequence>
                                    </xs:complexType>
                                </xs:element>
                            </xs:choice>
                        </xs:complexType>
                    </xs:element>
                </xs:schema>
                <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
                    <NewDataSet xmlns="">
                        <Table diffgr:id="Table1" msdata:rowOrder="0">
                            <ID>0010010533</ID>
                            <GRIFFE>SCOTCH</GRIFFE>
                            [...]
                        </Table>
                        <Table diffgr:id="Table2" msdata:rowOrder="1">
                            <ID>0010010606</ID>
                            <GRIFFE>VALUO </GRIFFE>
                            [...]
                        </Table> [more tables follow]
```

I'm losing my sanity in trying to get some consistent results, as the service has ~25 methods, and all the php soap utilities require a detailed wsdl specification. 
Is there any way to manually edit the wsdl file to convince code generators that the ws response is an array of tables and not a very long string, nearly impossible to parse?

edit: after some investigation I found out that `s:any` is used by .NET services to ensure compatibility (???), so is it a legit request to ask the web service maintainer to conform the wsdl to the real data scheme?

Thanks

Comment: No, you cannot edit the WSDL. 
(technically you *could* copy it and create your own version, but that's *really* poor practice). 

The [WSDL](https://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl) is auto-generated based on the actual SOAP service. If you're new to SOAP, you might want to have a look at the [examples](https://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl#_soap-b) provided by the W3 site, to get a basic grasp on what it is and how it works. 

SOAP as a whole is a topic that cannot be explained through a simple Q&A. Edit, Derek Banas has a pretty solid tutorial on YouTube, that might help as well.

Comment: Yeah, by editing I meant copying and using a local version; the ws is paleolithic, so I don't think there will be any feature change upcoming, still I get that doing that is poor practice.
But how can a wsdl be auto-generated and still be wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure to be honest. I've seen it before, recently I was working on a very old SOAP api that was supposed to deliver an XML object as per the WSDL, but gave me JSON instead. Your best bet is contacting the API supplier's tech support, because these issues tend to be very specific to the system you're working with, and thus impossible to answer without access to the system itself. It's one of the reasons I [and others with me](https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/3dloqk/soap_can_go_die_in_a_fire/) despise SOAP/WSDL-based web servers.

Comment: Check out WSI compliance if you want to understand how auto generated WSDL can be wrong. Simple things like how to present a null value in xml can be  pain. For example a null surname in a person xml object could be <surname/> or should it be <surname nillable="true"/> or should the tag be missing completely? I do a lot of WSDL authoring i.e. hand craft my own WSDL's so I could have a look but would need the WSDL code.